# Use of D3 and D5 in inverting circuit

Tags: diodes, npn

I have simulated this circuit in Spice and it works as it is supposed to, but I fail to understand the use of diodes D3 and D5.  I know it has something to do with T2 transistor.

Edit:

Correction R22 is 22 ohm and ERR_Out is pulled up to 15V externally (not shown in this circuit.)

Could some one explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: It makes T2 into a constant current sink. (Vbe=~1.2V and R22 determines the current)

Comment: My confusion was if R19 is set properly then we would not need the two diodes,or maybe use a zener in place if the exact voltage drop at Ve is known.

Comment: 2 1N4148 diodes are probably cheaper than a zener, and certainly cheaper than a  BC337 replacement with a tightly constrained beta which would be needed if you were relying on R19 to set the max current.

Answer (score 3):

My humble opinion is...
Only inverting stage is T2. That's why you have err_out = 1 when err_in = 0. Looking as voltage levels. 
T1 emitter follower adjusts to high impedance of err source circuit, and R18/R20 adjust high level err input (24V) to logic level 5V since obviously power supply of 74AC14 is 5V.

But inverting stage T2 is also constant current sink. 
That's what D2 and D3 are for. 
It will limit T2 base voltage to 1.4V. Since Ube is 0.7V, you will have 0.7 left for R22.
Constant current is 0.7/R22. 0.7/22=31mA
:)